# JavaScript how to return a string which looks like a double from a percentage calculation

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I am performing a simple percentage deduction from a price in javascript.

The original price is a string - "80.00" 
My Percentage to deduct is - 25

This is my calculation

result = "80.00" * (25/100); 
result is 20 
my desired result is 20.00

But type double doesn't exist in java script as far as i know

Comment: `result.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Kind user

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
(parseFloat("80.00") * (25/100)).toFixed(2);
```

I think this should your problem.

Comment: you don't need the parseFloat

Comment: Yes you are right in this example I don't need it.

Comment: I thought it's too trivial for a full reply but now I regret it xD

Comment: Kind User post as answer and I will accept